# Automating daily procedures

Tags: c#, visual-basic, vba

Is there a way to automate running VBA in Excel to clean up the file from inside an application?

Everyday my office has to confirm that 50 people have shown up for work on time. The scheduling software we use allows us to run a report and export in to 4 file types: HTML, RTF, CSV, and a text file. For what I am looking to do I have decided to use the Comma Separated Value export. I am able to import that CSV into Excel, clean it up, then import the results in MSSQL. What I am looking to do is run that section without any human interaction, other than specifying the file name of the CSV. My preferred language is C#, but I am flexible.

Comment: You say you know C#, but where exactly is your problem? You told us 3 steps: (1) load into Excel, (2) clean it up, (3) import results into MSSQL. For which of the 3 steps do you have problems to implement it? For (1) and (3) there are plenty of example on the web, just use Google, and about (2) you told us nothing, so it is pretty unclear if that's your problem.

Comment: Doc, I am just looking for a way to do steps 1-3 in one step. The other people that will be using this might not know what do to or may try to skip a step.

Comment: (Please use the @ sign as a prefix when you respond to someone, making your comment appear in the inbox of that person). Your comment clarifies nothing. If you know to do (1), (2) and (3) in C#, you will obviously know how to do 1-3 in one step. I guess it is step 2, but as long as you don't tell us what kind of "clean-up" you are doing, don't expect any reasonable answer. Voting to close until you edit your question and tell us where your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL Server to directly import CSV files without needing to go through Excel to perform "data clean up".

You have several methods to import data:

- T-SQL's [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command to load a CSV file. A good example is shown in [Import CSV file into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server) on StackOverflow.
- SQL Server Management Studio which can be automated using SSIS. [Importing data using SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG2N2iI0W3M)
- [bcp command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.90).aspx) line utility. It should be easy to export the CSV file to a single filename, which can then be scheduled to run automatically.
- [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026(v=sql.90).aspx) which was designed to load data from various sources. Different versions (i.e., 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, etc.) of SQL Server have different levels of capabilities. Please refer to the correct documentation for your version.
- Lastly, roll your own:

  - In a VBA environment (like Excel) you will have to use Visual Basic for Applications as C# is not supported.
  - A standalone application can load the CSV, make a connection to the database, and perform INSERTs (if you are using SQL to get the data there). Optionally, you can use an [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) ([nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) are two very popular ORMs) to load your data.